# Removing rows based on value in separate dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, filter, merge

I have a dataframe called corr_dat_cond1 which has trials of an experimental task.

```
    > head(corr_dat_cond1)
  participant search_difficulty key_resp.corr key_resp.rt target_position distractor1_colour distractor2_colour non_target_colour
1        1010              easy             1   1.1869998           right          [0,0.5,1]          [0,0.5,1]        [0,0.59,0]
2        1010         difficult             1   1.2490001            down      [0.82,0.31,0]      [0.82,0,0.31]     [0.82,0.31,0]
3        1010              easy             1   1.0100000              up          [0,0.5,1]         [0,0.59,0]        [0,0.59,0]
4        1010              easy             1   0.8659999            down          [0,0.5,1]          [0,0.5,1]        [0,0.59,0]
5        1010         no_search             1   0.8559999           right         [-1,-1,-1]         [-1,-1,-1]        [-1,-1,-1]
6        1010              easy             1   0.6269999           right          [0,0.5,1]         [0,0.59,0]        [0,0.59,0]
  non_target_pos cue_uposition target_char non_target_char cue_time           cue_colour cue_validity
1     [0,-0.328]            up           x               =      1.4 Mismatch (Onset) cue        FALSE
2      [0,0.328]          left           x               =      1.0 Mismatch (Onset) cue        FALSE
3      [0.328,0]          down           x               =      1.1 Mismatch (Onset) cue        FALSE
4      [0.328,0]         right           =               x      1.4    Match (Color) cue        FALSE
5     [-0.328,0]          down           =               x      1.4 Mismatch (Onset) cue        FALSE
6     [0,-0.328]         right           =               x      1.4    Match (Color) cue         TRUE
```

My second data frame is cond1_participant_meanrts, which has a high_cutoff and low_cutoff for each participant in each search_difficulty level.

```
    > head(cond1_participant_meanrts)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   participant [2]
  participant search_difficulty   mrt stdev low_cutoff high_cutoff
        <dbl> <chr>             <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
1         636 difficult         1.10  0.224     0.426         1.77
2         636 easy              0.986 0.270     0.177         1.79
3         636 no_search         0.909 0.298     0.0160        1.80
4         642 difficult         1.02  0.268     0.221         1.83
5         642 easy              0.887 0.237     0.175         1.60
6         642 no_search         0.809 0.225     0.135         1.48
```

I want to remove rows in corr_dat_cond1 if the key_resp.rt value is greater than the corresponding (based on participant and search_difficulty) high_cutoff value from cond1_participant_meanrts or if the key_resp.rt value is less than the corresponding low_cutoff value from cond1_participant_meanrts.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's easier for others to answer your question if you include some reproducible data, using ``dput(corr_dat_cond1)`` etc. Also including an example where corr_dat_cond1 and cond1_participant_meanrts have  common participant IDs would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
corr_dat_cond1 %>%
    dplyr::left_join(
        cond1_participant_meanrts, by=c("participant", "search_difficulty")
        ) %>%
    dplyr::filter(
        key_resp.rt < high_cutoff | key_resp.rt > low_cutoff
        )
```